# Can this chart read from json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, anychart

I'm currently using the following chart to display data. The chart currently reads `json` data embedded into the `javascript`.

I need to be able to read from file `any.json` instead of the embedded `json` object. I've been searching for some type of documentation, but have found nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

`any.json` looks like this:

```
[{x: "January", value: 10000},{x: "February", value: 12000},{x: "March", value: 18000}]
```

And here's the current html:

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
  chart = anychart.fromJson({
    chart: {
      type: "line",
      series: [{
        seriesType: "spline",
        data: [{
            x: "January",
            value: 10000
          },
          {
            x: "February",
            value: 12000
          },
          {
            x: "March",
            value: 18000
          },
          {
            x: "April",
            value: 11000
          },
          {
            x: "May",
            value: 9000
          }
        ]
      }],
      container: "container"
    }
  }).draw();
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.13.1/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.13.1/anychart-ui.min.css" />
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.13.1/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/latest/anychart-ui.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://api.anychart.com/7.13.1/anychart.data#loadJsonFile method. There is a sample: https://playground.anychart.com/api/7.13.1/modules/anychart.data.loadJsonFile-plain